# Difference between using ObjectIdentifier() and '===' Operator

Tags: swift, equatable

Let's say I'm implementing a root class in Swift, which I declare adopts the `Equatable` protocol (I want to be able to tell if an array of my type contains a given instance or not).

**What is the difference** -if any, in this specific case- between implementing the protocol's required `==` operator as:

```
public static func ==(lhs: MyClass, rhs: MyClass) -> Bool {

    return ObjectIdentifier(lhs) == ObjectIdentifier(rhs)
}
```

...as opposed to just doing this:

```
public static func ==(lhs: MyClass, rhs: MyClass) -> Bool {

    return (lhs === rhs)
}
```

---

As a reference, this is what the documentation says about `ObjectIdentifier()`:

> A unique identifier for a class instance or metatype. In Swift, only
>   class instances and metatypes have  unique identities. There is no
>   notion of identity for structs, enums, functions, or tuples.

...and this is what the "Basic Operators" section of [The Swift Programming Language (Swift 3)](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/BasicOperators.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH6-ID60) says about the `===` operator:

> NOTE
>
> Swift also provides two identity operators (`===` and `!==`), which you use to test whether two object references both refer to the same object instance. For more information, see Classes and Structures.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There is no difference for class instance, see the following
[comments in ObjectIdentifier.swift](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/stdlib/public/core/ObjectIdentifier.swift#L32):

```
  /// Creates an instance that uniquely identifies the given class instance.
  ///
  /// The following example creates an example class `A` and compares instances
  /// of the class using their object identifiers and the identical-to
  /// operator (`===`):
  ///
  ///     class IntegerRef {
  ///         let value: Int
  ///         init(_ value: Int) {
  ///             self.value = value
  ///         }
  ///     }
  ///
  ///     let x = IntegerRef(10)
  ///     let y = x
  ///
  ///     print(ObjectIdentifier(x) == ObjectIdentifier(y))
  ///     // Prints "true"
  ///     print(x === y)
  ///     // Prints "true"
  ///
  ///     let z = IntegerRef(10)
  ///     print(ObjectIdentifier(x) == ObjectIdentifier(z))
  ///     // Prints "false"
  ///     print(x === z)
  ///     // Prints "false"
  ///
```

It also becomes apparent from the 
[implementation of `==` for `ObjectIdentifier`](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/stdlib/public/core/ObjectIdentifier.swift#L84),
which just compares the pointers to the object storage:

```
  public static func == (x: ObjectIdentifier, y: ObjectIdentifier) -> Bool {
    return Bool(Builtin.cmp_eq_RawPointer(x._value, y._value))
  }
```

which is what [the `===` operator](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/stdlib/public/core/Equatable.swift#L235)
does as well:

```
public func === (lhs: AnyObject?, rhs: AnyObject?) -> Bool {
  switch (lhs, rhs) {
  case let (l?, r?):
    return Bool(Builtin.cmp_eq_RawPointer(
        Builtin.bridgeToRawPointer(Builtin.castToUnknownObject(l)),
        Builtin.bridgeToRawPointer(Builtin.castToUnknownObject(r))
      ))
  case (nil, nil):
    return true
  default:
    return false
  }
}
```

`ObjectIdentifier` conforms to `Hashable`, so it is useful if you want to implement that protocol for your class:

```
extension MyClass: Hashable {
    var hashValue: Int {
        return ObjectIdentifier(self).hashValue
    }
}
```

An object identifier can also be created for meta types
(e.g. `ObjectIdentifier(Float.self)`) for which `===` is not defined.

Comment: Thank you for the very detailed answer. I was expecting no big different for my own class types, but this is very enlightening. I should have thought of checking the source code myself, now that Swift is open source!

Comment: `===` operator [now directly compares](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/b330c6078fd233ea7206158a20b21b4672d75cc3/stdlib/public/core/Equatable.swift#L249) `ObjectIdentifier` of parameters.