# How to remove specific object from array?

Tags: arrays, swift, xcode8, option-type

If the caller passes in an object of type MyDelegate and it is in the array, I want to remove it from the array.

```
protocol MyDelegate {
}

private var delegates = [MyDelegate]()
...
...
func removeDelegate(_ delegate: MyDelegate) {
    if let index = self.delegates.index(where: { $0 == delegate }) {
        log.trace("Removing delegate \(delegate)");
        self.delegates.remove(at: index)
    }
}
```

1. Is there a less complicated way to do this?
2. This conditional, "{ $0 == delegate }", is causing the error, "Cannot convert value of type '(*OptionalNilComparisonType) -> Bool' to expected argument type '(*) -> Bool'".  How can I fix this?  I've tried adding ? and ! but still not fully understanding Swift's optional concept.

I am using Xcode 8.2.1 and Swift 3(?).

Comment: Are the delegates supposed to be instances of *classes?*  Then you can define a "class protocol" `protocol MyDelegate: class { }` and use the identity operator for comparison: `index(where: { $0 === delegate })`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1. Is there a less complicated way to do this?

You *could* omit `self` when accessing the `delegates` member, and bake the resulting index of the `index(where:)` call into a call to the `map` method of `Optional`:

```
func removeDelegate(_ delegate: MyDelegate) {
    delegates.index(where: { $0 == delegate})
        .map { delegates.remove(at: $0) }
}
```

In case no such `delegate` object is found, the expression above simply results `nil` (non-captured result).

---

> This conditional, "`{ $0 == delegate }`", is giving causing the error,
>   "Cannot convert value of type '`(OptionalNilComparisonType) -> Bool`' to
>   expected argument type '`() -> Bool`'". How can I fix this? I've tried
>   adding `?` and `!` but still not fully understanding Swift's optional
>   concept.

This is yet another example of a kind of obscure error message in Swift. The core error is that `MyDelegate` does not have an `==` operator defined (does not conform to `Equatable`).

After your edit you showed, however, that `MyDelegate` is a protocol, so if you let this conform to `Equatable`, you wont be able to (as it will be contain a `Self` type requirement) use `MyDelegate` as a concrete type (only as e.g. type constraint on a generic).

If your concrete delegate objects are reference ones (`class`), and you want to test object equality in the sense of testing if both refer to the same object (object reference), you could make use of the the [`Object​Identifier`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/objectidentifier) available to class instances. Constraining `MyDelegate` (after your edit you showed it to be a protocol) to only classes,

```
protocol MyDelegate: class { /* ... */ }
```

and testing the equality of the `ObjectIdentifier` in the `index(where:)` call above:

```
func removeDelegate(_ delegate: MyDelegate) {
    delegates.index(where: { ObjectIdentifier($0) == ObjectIdentifier(delegate) })
        .map { delegates.remove(at: $0) }
}
```

Looking at the source code for `ObjectIdentifier`, we see that this will compare the underlying raw ptr values of two `delegate` instances; from [swift/stdlib/public/core/ObjectIdentifier.swift](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/stdlib/public/core/ObjectIdentifier.swift#L84):

> ```
> public static func == (x: ObjectIdentifier, y: ObjectIdentifier) -> Bool {
>   return Bool(Builtin.cmp_eq_RawPointer(x._value, y._value))
> }
> ```

---

As mentioned by @MartinR in the comments to the question above, rather than going via `ObjectIdentifier`, you could also use the `===` identity operator for class instances directly.

```
func removeDelegate(_ delegate: MyDelegate) {
    delegates.index(where: { $0 === delegate })
        .map { delegates.remove(at: $0) }
}
```

For completeness, we may verify that `===` make use of the same `Builtin` method as the `==` operator for `ObjectIdentifier`, by having a look at [swift/stdlib/public/core/Equatable.swift](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/stdlib/public/core/Equatable.swift#L235):

> ```
> public func === (lhs: AnyObject?, rhs: AnyObject?) -> Bool {
>   switch (lhs, rhs) {
>   case let (l?, r?):
>     return Bool(Builtin.cmp_eq_RawPointer(
>         Builtin.bridgeToRawPointer(Builtin.castToUnknownObject(l)),
>         Builtin.bridgeToRawPointer(Builtin.castToUnknownObject(r))
>       ))
>   case (nil, nil):
>     return true
>   default:
>     return false
>   }
> }
> ```

Comment: Is there no Swift concept of default object equality like in java and c#?

Comment: @RichAmberale generally, no. There is the [`Object​Identifier`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/objectidentifier) available to class instances, so if you constraint `MyDelegate` (after your edit you showed it to be a protocol) to only classes, you could test the equality of the `ObjectIdentifier`:s of `$0` and `delegate` above. This is in essence testing if the both refer (object reference) to the same object, and not if they are equal in the sense of some pre-defined `==` operator.

Comment: Comparing the ObjectIdentifier is the same as checking identity with `===`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39587027/difference-between-using-objectidentifier-and-operator.

Comment: @MartinR thanks for the link! I saw the same comment section in the source of `ObjectIdentifier`, but was in the progress of looking around for the actual implementation of `===` (to verify that it most likely calls the same `Builtin` method).

Comment: Thanks! In this new enlightened state of understanding I changed MyDelegate to extend NSObjectProtocol and updated the func, which so far at least compiles:

    `func removeDelegate(_ delegate: MyDelegate) {
        delegates.index(where: { $0.isEqual(delegate) })
            .map {
                delegates.remove(at: $0)
                log.trace("Removed delegate \(delegate)");
        }
    }`

Comment: @MartinR found it in [`Equatable`](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/stdlib/public/core/Equatable.swift#L235)! Possibly worth adding to your linked answer.

Comment: @RichAmberale happy to help. It might be a personal preference, but I usually avoid, myself, resorting to Obj-C features when using Swift, so I would probably prefer `===` / `ObjectIdentifier` over `NSObjectProtocol`:s `isEqual(...)` method myself.

Comment: @MartinR btw, any thoughts on why the concrete `l` and `r` `AnyObject` instances in the `===` impl. above would be processed through `Builtin.castToUnknownObject(...)` prior to being passed to `Buildin.bridgeToRawPointer(...)`, when this is not the case for the initializer (by concrete `AnyObject`) of [`ObjectIdentifier`](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/stdlib/public/core/ObjectIdentifier.swift#L61)? Does this look like an inconsistency, or am I missing something obvious?

Comment: Thanks for the link, I have updated the other answer. – I have no idea. From https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/include/swift/AST/Builtins.def it seems unnecessary: "CastToUnknownObject has type (T) -> Builtin.UnknownObject."  and "BridgeToRawPointer has type (T) -> Builtin.RawPointer"  – But I have no deeper knowledge of "built-in SIL operations" :)