# ObjectIdentifier needed for Swift equality?

Tags: ios, swift, skspritenode, sknode

We have multiple instances of a custom Swift class, which inherits from SKSpriteNode, and were able to execute the following code (grossly simplified for this question) correctly:

```
let instance1 = CustomClass()
let instance2 = CustomClass()
let instance3 = CustomClass()
let instance4 = CustomClass()

let array1 = [instance1, instance2]
let array2 = [instance3, instance4]

func check(testInstance: CustomClass) -> Bool {
   return array1.filter({ $0 == testInstance }).count > 0
}

check(testInstance: instance3)
```

In other words, executing `check(testInstance: instance3)` returned `false` as expected.

However, we made a bunch of changes, and `check` stopped working.

`CustomClass` does not implement the `Equatable` protocol. We just want to detect unique instances.

It only started working when we used `ObjectIdentifier`, meaning the function changed to this:

```
func check(testInstance: CustomClass) -> Bool {
   return array1.filter({ ObjectIdentifier($0) == ObjectIdentifier(testInstance) }).count > 0
}
```

Why is `ObjectIdentifier` needed, and when should it be used for object equality?

This was written with Swift 3.

Comment: It's basically `===`, see this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39587027/difference-between-using-objectidentifier-and-operator

Comment: @Hamish identity comparison, not looking for comparison of properties

Comment: @Sweeper why did it work before without ===, i.e., only using == worked? The goal is to understand that.

Comment: @Crashalot You just want `===` then. We can't know why it no longer works with `==` without seeing how the `==` overload for `CustomClass` is implemented (but semantically, `==` shouldn't be used for an identity comparison). Did you implement a `CustomClass` overload of `==`? If not, I suspect it inherits from `NSObject`, in which case it gets an `==` overload that just calls `isEquals(_:)` – so by default does an identity comparison. I guess you must have overriden `isEquals(_:)` in that case and implemented it to actually perform an equality check.

Comment: @Hamish thanks for the fast reply. there was no `==` overload for `CustomClass`, this is what's baffling.

Comment: @Crashalot So it inherits from `NSObject`? If you command-click on the `==` operator, Xcode will take you to the overload that's being called.

Comment: @Hamish great idea. it inherits from `SKNode`.

Comment: @Crashalot Which then inherits from `NSObject` :) So the implementation of `isEqual(_:)` is likely where you need to be looking.

Comment: @Hamish sorry `SKSpriteNode` which is why `ios` was an original tag

Comment: @Hamish yup, just did command-click as you suggested, and it appears the `==` function from `NSObject` is used.

Comment: `array1.filter({ $0 == testInstance }).count > 0` -> just use `contains(where:)`: `array1.contains(where: { $0 == testInstance })`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why is `ObjectIdentifier` needed, and when should it be used for object equality?

You don't need to use `ObjectIdentifier` in order to perform an identity comparison in this case, you can simply use the identity operator [`===`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/1538988) instead which, as [Martin says here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39587589/2976878), for class instances is equivalent to using `ObjectIdentifier`'s `==` overload:

```
func check(testInstance: CustomClass) -> Bool {
    return array1.contains(where: { $0 === testInstance })
}
```

Also note we're using `contains(where:)` over `filter{...}.count > 0`, as the former will short-circuit upon finding a matching element, whereas the latter evaluates the entire sequence (and creates an unnecessary intermediate array).

The direct use of `==` to perform an identity comparison of objects *may* have worked due to the fact that `CustomClass` ultimately inherits from `NSObject`, which conforms to `Equatable` by defining [an `==` overload](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/stdlib/public/SDK/ObjectiveC/ObjectiveC.swift#L215) that calls [`isEqual(_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/objectivec/nsobject/1393823-isequal), which by default performs an identity comparison.

However in general, this should *not* be relied upon – the implementation of `isEqual(_:)` can be overridden to perform a comparison based on property values rather than identity. Furthermore, semantically `Equatable` requires that the implementation of `==` is based all on visible aspects (i.e property values) of the instances being compared.

From [the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/equatable):

> Equality implies substitutability — any two instances that compare
>   equally can be used interchangeably in any code that depends on their
>   values. To maintain substitutability, the `==` operator should take into
>   account all visible aspects of an `Equatable` type.

Therefore using `==` for an identity comparison on your class was never correct, even though it may have worked initially.

As for when `ObjectIdentifier` should be used, really you should never need it *just* to perform an identity comparison. For classes, you should use the `===` operator, and for metatypes, you should simply use the [`==`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/1541152) overload defined specifically for them (as in that case, identity just happens to equality, as each new metatype instance is unique).

The main use of `ObjectIdentifier` is really its `hashValue` implementation, which is derived from the pointer value of the thing that it's initialised with. This can be useful, for example, in allowing metatypes to be `Dictionary` keys (compare [Make a Swift dictionary where the key is "Type"?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42459484/2976878)).

Comment: such a superb response, wish i could award you 10x the points :)

Comment: is `contains` new to swift 3? someone advised using `filter` before, but maybe that was before `contains` existed? thanks again!

Comment: @Crashalot Happy to help! And `contains` has been around since the days of Swift 1 :) Although back then it was a top-level function – it became an instance method of `Sequence(Type)` in Swift 2.

Comment: Darn you and your 23K points worth of knowledge! You took away the only good excuse for using `filter` and not `contains`! Now all that's left is 'bad developer' hahaha. :) Thanks again!